# Publish to someone else's Azure subscription?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, publish

I have a web application that currently runs on Azure under my own Azure subscription. I'd like to transfer this to another party so that they can run the web application under their subscription. How can I do this?

Can I:

1. Give them some sort of package that they can publish (ideally I'd like to avoid giving them the actual source code), or
2. get connection details from them so that I can publish directly from Visual Studio to their subscription (said connection details would have to *not* give me full control over their subscription)?

Note that the web application consists of a website, an Azure SQL database, and a Blob container.

Comment: Would you require access to the web app in other party's subscription for a longer period of time or is it like one time thing?

Comment: @GauravMantri: probably a one-time thing, though as well as publishing I might have to help them get the DB set up, etc.

Comment: Do take a look at @David's answer below (with my comments). Temporarily your client can grant you access to just one resource group in their subscription. You login, set up everything, do the deployment and then your client can remove you from their subscription (or keep you there in a reader role so that you can check from time to time but not make any changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure now has the Resource Manager API (ARM). One of the features: Resource Groups. A resource group serves as a bounding box for a set of resources (web apps, VMs, etc.). You can grant permissions on a resource group, allowing someone external to your subscription/organization to work within that resource group. With `owner` permission, they'd be able to create new resources within that group, and never be able to see anything beyond the resource group.

Comment: 3 corrections/suggestions: 1) The permission should be the other way around. The client should grant Gary permission on a resource group in their subscription so that Gary can deploy the application in their subscription. 2) instead of `owner` permission, I would recommend `contributor` permission. 3) I would not even mention co-admin thing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with point 1: If I own a sub, and want you to work within it, I must grant you permissions on the RG in my sub. 2) contributor is limited when creating new resources (but may work for most scenarios). 3) only added for completeness, but probably a good idea to punt on it.

Comment: 1) My understanding is that Gary has built an application for his client and now wants to transfer this application to them and hence the comment (may be I misunderstood). 2) Giving owner permission is dangerous because this would allow Gary to add another users to that resource group or change user roles in that resource group. A contributor is essentially an owner but doesn't have permission to change the roles and manage users.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. However, I tried this by creating a new email address, creating a new Microsoft account using that email address, creating an Azure subscription with that account, creating a resource group in that subscription, and finally adding my normal Microsoft account as a user with Contributor permission for that resource group. All of that seemed to go OK, but despite me clicking "invite" and it claiming that everything went OK, I never received any email or other notification, and I can't figure out how to actually get in using my normal account. What *should* have happened?

Comment: Ah, I found it... There was no welcome email, no alert in the portal, nothing extra listed in the subscriptions or resources blades, nothing at all to indicate that I'd been added, and so far as I could see nothing mentioned anywhere in the help on-line. However I happened to click on the 'profile' drop-down at the top of the screen, and noticed that it had two 'directories, listed, both named 'default directory'. When I selected the second one, I could see the stuff from the other subscription. So it seems to work - it's just not at all obvious where to find it. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

The best method would be for them to provide you the publish profile that they can download from the Azure web application dashboard.

[image]

This provides you a file you can import into your project that will publish to that Azure subscription.  The information contained in the publish settings file is a unique userId and password to that web application only (you can open the file with Notepad and read its contents).

If you need to interact with the database directly, you will need the SQL username and password as well as they would need to open the SQL Azure firewall to allow your IP address to connect to it.

Interacting with the blob container could be done using the Blob APIs (or some of the various GUI tools out there) and a key with the proper read/write accesses attached to it.